# Recursive procedure in genexus

Tags: genexus

I have one table called Cattegorys that have CategoryId in primary key and CategoryParentId (auto-relationship).

I need to return all Category name parent of my data in the property "CategoryParentsName".

In my CategorysSDT i create this property varchar:

```
CategoryParentsName VARCHAR(500);
```

My data provider:

```
CategoriasSDT
{
    data
    {
        order (CategoryName) when &sort = 'CategoryName-desc'
        {
            CategoryId= CategoryId
            CategoryName= CategoriaNome
            CategoryParentId = CategoryParentId
            CategoryParentsName= CategoryParentsName
        }
    }
}
```

In my transaction i create a formula to my property CategoryParentsName that calls this procedure:

```
&isTrue = true
&isAchou = true
do while (&isTrue)
    if &isAchou
            &isAchou = false    
            for each
                where CategoriaId = &CategoryParentId
                &CategoryParentsName = CategoryName+ " > test"
                &isAchou = true
            endfor
        else
            &isTrue = false
    endif
enddo
```

In my property categoryParentsName i'm receiving the correct name of the category parents but the CategoryParentId is returning null.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your scenario, but I believe you are making the "autorelashonship" by hand and maybe not assigning CategoryParentId properly. If that's the case I'd recommend you create a subtype group _CategoryParent_ (`CategoryParentId` sbt `ParentId`, `CategoryParentsName` sbt `CategoryName`) and let GeneXus handle the relashionship. Then you wouldn't need the procedure that computes the parents name and the dataprovider should be able to load all your desired data directly.

Comment: @gusbro in my transaction the CategoryParents name must be a type CategoriesSDT or CategoryName?

Comment: If you create the subtype group i mentioned then it would be a CategoryName

Comment: i created the subtype group but my procedure is getting infinite loop. I need the "tree" categorys name